# How to add a Multiple TableViewCell with different number of Repetition for each of them

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have TableView that has 3 TableViewCell inside it.

- First TableViewCell has : Label
- Second TableViewCell has : TextField
- Third TableViewCell has : Button

My problem is U want to have a different number of repetition for each of them.

For example, I want my first tableViewCell to repeat 3 times, second tableViewCell to repeat 2 times, and third tableViewCell to repeat 2 times.

The TableView will be like this:

1. Label
2. Label
3. Label
4. TextField
5. TextField
6. Button
7. Button

My code:

```
import UIKit

class FilterPage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let PropertTypeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PropertyTypeCell")
             return PropertTypeCell!
        }  else if indexPath.row == 1{
            let PriceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PriceCell")
            return PriceCell!
        }
        else{
            let RoomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RoomCell")
            return RoomCell!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the count of each type of cell fixed? In other words, will there always be 3 labels, 2 text fields, and 2 buttons?

Comment: Yes, It's Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this cases I like to make an array of `CellTypes`, I define a enum type in this case CellType

```
enum CellType {
    case PropertyTypeCell
    case PriceCell
    case RoomCell
}
```

then in one method I populate an array of `CellType` if you want dynamic, in your case you can use a initialization like this

```
var cellTypes : [CellType] = [.PropertyTypeCell,.PropertyTypeCell,.PropertyTypeCell,.PriceCell,.PriceCell,.RoomCell,.RoomCell]
```

After this you can return in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.cellTypes.count
}
```

And most important you can forgot the IndexPath nightmare, only getting which `CellType` is the current one you can do something like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let celltype = self.cellTypes[indexPath.row]
    switch celltype {
    case .PropertyTypeCell:
        let PropertTypeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PropertyTypeCell")
        return PropertTypeCell!
    case .PriceCell:
        let PriceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PriceCell")
        return PriceCell!
    default:
        let RoomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RoomCell")
        return RoomCell!

    }
}
```

This method allows you, change your table structure without touch your cellForRowAtIndexPath method and without take in account your indexpaths.rows numbers which can be very tricky